# Searching, sorting and paging not working for datatable laravel

Tags: php, laravel, datatable

So I'm trying to use the datatable as seen in my code written below. Unfortunately for some unknown reasons the functions for sorting, searching and paging does not work. May I know what did I missed out or the reason for it not working?

```
@extends('app')
@section('header')
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
@stop
@section('content')

<h1 class="page-header">View Log Information</h1>
<br/>

<div class="container">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12" style="overflow:auto">
    <table class="table table-hover" id="logTable">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                User
            </th>

            <th>
                Log Description
            </th>
            <th>
                Time Stamp
            </th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        @foreach ($logs as $log)
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    {{ App\User::find($log->user_id)->name }}
                </td>

                <td>
                    {{ $log->log_description }}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{ date("F d Y - g:i a",strtotime("$log->created_at")) }}
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        @endforeach
    </table>
    </div>
</div>

@stop

@section('scripts')
    <!-- Bootstrap Based Data Table Plugin Script-->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#logTable').DataTable();
    } );
    </script>
@stop
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
<table class="table table-hover" id="logTable">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            User
        </th>

        <th>
            Log Description
        </th>
        <th>
            Time Stamp
        </th>
    </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        @foreach ($logs as $log)
        <tr>
            <td>
                {{ App\User::find($log->user_id)->name }}
            </td>

            <td>
                {{ $log->log_description }}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{ date("F d Y - g:i a",strtotime("$log->created_at")) }}
            </td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody> 
</table>
```

Move the `@foreach` statement under tbody. It's not working because you keep duplicating the `tbody` instead of `<tr>` inside the `<tbody>`.

And this is just a suggestion. Don't do the `query` at view. it's not a good practice. Do all the query inside controller. You can use [Laravel Relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships) for `App\User::find($log->user_id)->name`.

Comment: Thank you so much! =) Ahh yeah, thanks for reminding about the query part. Yeah controller .. Thanks =)